# How to transfer another parameter with an ajax state change

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code in my ajax query:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
```

and the function stateChange is `function stateChange(event)`

Is it possible to add a second parameter to the function so it doesn't just passes a number as well as the event?

I've tried doing `xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange(event,'123');` with function `stateChange(event,num)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure that allows your event handling function access to those variables.

Instead of

```
xhr.blahblah;
xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
xhr.blahblah;
```

This technique creates an anonymous function that gives scope to your '123' variable:

```
xhr.blahblah;
function (xhrObj, callbackFn, param) {
  xhrObj.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    callbackFn(event, param);
  };
}(xhr, stateChange, '123');
xhr.blahblah;
```

Comment: Beaten to the SO punch, but I like my answer better.  `xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) { stateChange(event, param); };` would have the *exact same effect* without all the scaffolding you've built here.

Comment: Unless you load up a pile of xhr requests at once, and need the value '123' to be contained in a variable and different for each request.

Comment: You mean if you're in a `for` loop or something and keep changing the value of the variable `param`?  Do it in a jQuery `$.each` loop, which will provide a separate closure for each version.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, sort of:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) { stateChange(event,'123'); };
```

would do what you say you want, but it isn't clear to me that what you say you want is what you need.